# What can I do if I feel someone is editing a specific question to change the meaning in bad faith?

Tags: discussion

I made a question, is this

[Does iTunes 11 need extra services or tools to manage duplicates in the library?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73421/how-itunes-11-manage-duplicates)

The core of the question is "Maybe iTunes 11 finds and delete them automagically?"

It is got edited TWICE to remove my rant AND it has been closed as a duplicate question because it has been changed to "how i can find duplicated songs".

It's not a duplicate question, and I wish to have it reopened.

I have the feeling that the editor had a reaction like "OMG this guy is so wrong, iTunes 11 is a masterpiece, Apple can't be wrong"

What might I do to help with this post?

Comment: Votes on meta are odd. I upvote things I don't agree with since I appreciate the discussion and want everyone to see it. Others downvote things they don't agree with (and I think most long time SO/SE users vote that way) - c'est la vie in an open system ...

Comment: I'm a big fan of constructive discourse, whether someone agrees with me or not. I'm not a big fan of rants and name-calling. I think Apple makes some great products, and some of Apple's products frustrate me incredibly. But when the first word of the title of a meta post calls editors on this site a derogatory name and assumes they have malicious intent, I'll happily vote against the post (if not close or delete it) because name-calling is rarely conducive to figuring out truth. That said, the answers and comments on this post seem quite constructive.

Answer (score 8):

I felt there was a valid question in there (how can I removes dupes on iTunes 11 for Windows), but if your main reaction after we take the time to edit it to a proper form is to insist on ranting instead of posing answerable questions and calling names, your questions have no place in our community.

As I commented on the question, have a look at the FAQ to learn how to ask questions here.

Comment: Sorry, the radical changes that every time Apple is imposing "with surprise" made me "see red", and write the question in the wrong way. You are right to enforce a policy, otherwise every question will become a fight. I was wrong, edited the question and removed comments.

Answer (score 5):

I'm glad you came here and posted. I was pondering whether to delete your entire thread - reverse the editing and let your mild insults stand so people could just know you've got an opinion and decide to move on or commiserate and stand by you. I am certain that many feel exactly like you - perhaps even several Apple fans.

I haven't had chance to have a second moderator look at your posts - but I'll be sure to have another have a look to make sure we're comfortable as a group closing it.

I don't want anyone getting bullied here - but when you walk in and call people fanboys - it's hard to respect the words you are writing since the first thought that comes when I see someone resorting to names over logic is "I'd sure rather this person explained how they are not a hater or troll before resorting to dismissing others as fans."

I'll start a private chat to see what you want your question to be and if I can help you get it on the site. Have a look at this question and comments in the mean time:

- [How can I downgrade iTunes 11 to 10.7 in Mountain Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/73191/5472)

We have a lot of people showing up and using terms like "hate, stupid, fanboy" and we are trying to keep things on a level where in a month - people don't have to go back and retract things they said because they didn't like that something changed on them. I’ve edited your post here to remove the term that has an argumentative tone to see if people are willing to change their votes. The edit history will help anyone that wonders where the fanboy wording originated.

While I'm thinking things over - would you go back and edit the question that is currently closed (still searchable, still editable, still re-openable by any 5 users that like it and have reputation on the site to reopen votes) and word it to be exactly what you wish? You can totally revert my edits - build on them or re-write it from scratch.

I'd like to act on something you feel captures your intent perfectly and not in reaction to flags or comments or how it was worded initially.

Comment: I reread your question as originally posted. I can see three answers you are seeking: 1) use some third party windows tool to make up for iTunes no longer offering the function 2) someone to say from experience that iTunes match will fix your sizable duplicate problem or will not fix it (so you can decide to pay or not pay) 3) someone to show you step by step how to go back to iTunes 10 on windows.  Did I miss the intent of your question?

Comment: No no I don't want to rollback to iTunes 10, I want to have the 11, I like the UI. What I meant is that now my duplicate mp3 are "missing" when I search them, so I wonder if iTunes got rid of them automatically.

Comment: OK - I'll reopen it and work to get you and any potential editors to come to a mutual agreement on how to word the question. Please hit us up here or in the chat room if you would like moderator assistance in getting all of the editors on board. In a nutshell - as long as there isn't an edit war where things go back/forth/back - we expect people to work out edits in the chat rooms. Flag things and moderators will help out as needed.

Comment: ok, I didnt' consider the chat room for that

Answer (score 3):

To add my two cents: If the whole purpose of your question is to ask whether iTunes 11 finds and somehow flags duplicates automatically, just rewrite it accordingly and request a reopen. It is most likely a rhetorical question but I still might support you in reopening then.

But please also understand that the original wording of the question appeared to more of a rant about a removed feature (and Apple in general) than a serious question. Statements like "forever, because Apple doesn't listen to users" and some of the comments just don't instill too much confidence to the contrary.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to ask if it does find them automatically. After all, this can be a good reason to remove the feature (do it without asking and keep the best file - that's what I was doing manually... if it does it automatically that would be great!). Then, I was angry for that and I wrote the question in a totally wrong way. Sorry.